# Custom validator with parameter is not working for textbox and checkbox in angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, customvalidator, angular-custom-validators

In my reactive form, I have a textbox and a checkbox. I want that when the checkbox is checked, then textbox can be null or empty. If checkbox is not checked then validation message should be shown for required value. So I have written a custom validator with parameter. But the validator is not working The form code is below:

```
<form [formGroup]="frmExpenseHead">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="Code" class="col-sm-12 col-form-label">Code</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="txtCode" id="code" name="code" formControlName="code"
        [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.code.errors }">
      <div *ngIf="submitted && f.code.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
        <div *ngIf="f.code.errors.conditionRequired">Code is required</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2 form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="chkAutoCode" id="autoCode" name="autoCode"
        formControlName="autoCode">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="autoCode">
        Auto Generate
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-primary mr-1" (click)="onSubmit()">Register</button>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="reset" (click)="onReset()">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

The ts file code is:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-expense-head',
  templateUrl: './expense-head.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./expense-head.component.css']
})
export class ExpenseHeadComponent implements OnInit {
  frmExpenseHead: FormGroup;
  today = this.calendar.getToday();
  submitted = false;

  txtCode: string;
  chkAutoCode: boolean = false;
  txtDate: NgbDateStruct;
  txtTitle: string;
  txtDescription: string;

  constructor(private calendar: NgbCalendar) { }

  ngOnInit() {    
    this.frmExpenseHead = new FormGroup({
      code: new FormControl("", [conditionalRequired(this.chkAutoCode)]),
      autoCode: new FormControl("")          
    });
  }

  get f() { return this.frmExpenseHead.controls; }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;

    if (this.frmExpenseHead.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    alert('SUCCESS!! :-)\n\n' + JSON.stringify(this.frmExpenseHead.value, null, 4));
  }

  onReset() {
    this.submitted = false;
    this.frmExpenseHead.reset();
  }
}
```

And the custom validator is:

```
export function conditionalRequired(bValue: boolean): ValidatorFn {  
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {

    let controlValue = control.value;    

    if (bValue === true) {      
      return null;
    }
    
    if (controlValue === "" || controlValue === null || controlValue === undefined) {
      return { "conditionRequired": true }
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

Can anybody let me know where is the problem? Please follow the below link for a workable example.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-validator-example?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create a custom validator for that, use the availible tools. It'll be much easier for you.

You can subscribe to any change of value of your checkbox `FormControl` and then change and update your input `FormControl`. Here's an example for you:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  public fg: FormGroup;
  public checkbox: FormControl = new FormControl(false);
  public input: FromControl = new FormControl('', Validators.required);

  public constructor() { }

  public ngOnInit(): void {    
    this.fg = new FormGroup({
      checkbox: this.checkbox,
      input: this.input          
    });
    this.checkbox.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      if (value) {
        this.input.setValidators(null);
      } else {
        this.input.setValidators(Validators.required);
      }
      this.input.updateValueAndValidity();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Yes it helps. But still I want to know what is the wrong in my code. As I am new to angular, I am trying to learn it better. Can you please help me to show where the wrong is in my code

Comment: Can't find what's wrong sorry. Maybe if you look at this post you can find it yourself: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-create-custom-validators-in-angular . You should still use the method shown above.